# post button value to different html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I have 2 buttons that update my `datatable` when they are clicked,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
            function seta() {
                document.let.out.value = "s"
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" name="let">

            <input type=BUTTON value="s" onclick="seta()">


            <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
                <td width="177" align="left"><strong>eggs</strong></td>
                </TR>

                <td><output type=TEXT name="out" size=60 enabled>  </td>
                </TR>

                <td><output type=TEXT name="poo" size=60 disabled>  </td>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I want to achieve is to have the buttons in one html file, say `page1.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
            function seta() {
                document.let.out.value = "s"
            }
        </script>



    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="#" name="let">


            <input type=BUTTON value="s" onclick="seta();">


    <body />
<html />
```

Which would update the `datatable` in a different html file, say `page2`,

```
<html>

    <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
      src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js">
          }

            function seta() {
                document.let.out.value = "s"

            }



        </script>

    </head>




    <body>
        <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1">
            <td width="177" align="left"><strong>eggs</strong></td>
            </TR>

            <td><output type=TEXT name="out" size=60 disabled></td>
            </TR>

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am pretty much a complete noob to this so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Your html is bit messy. F.e. you are closing </tr> but there is no <tr>...what is your problem? How to catch the values or how to send them? or both? Do you want to do everything with js? Because I recommend doing this in php since js is executed on clientside.

Comment: ye it's a bit messy sorry about that, i just started sketching this yesterday, i only have a really basic knowledge of js and know nothing of php, ye when i click a button on "page1" i want the table on "page2" to update, so ye send the button click from "page1" to be recieved by "page2" where the table will be... i was reading about Ajax but i could only get a static <div id="2">value</div> to load so far

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with AJAX or a similar technology involving an active server. One of your pages would push some information to the server and the other one would retrieve it from the server, updating its value.

Without using server-side technology which, if you are a "complete noob" as you say, you might be more comfortable with, you could accomplish this using an [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp). Create a page with two iframes, one with the page containing the buttons and another one with whatever the buttons are manipulating.

A quick search revealed [this page](http://coursesweb.net/javascript/get-change-iframe-through-another-iframe_t), telling you how to manipulate the contents of an iframe from another iframe.

I would add, however, that you should consider if you really need the files to be separate. If you want one page being viewed in a browser to change another file while it's still on the server, then you won't be able to using only Javascript and it's probably a bad idea to begin with. However, if both files are part of the same layout being displayed in the same browser concurrently, then why do they need to be separate? Can't you combine them into one larger HTML file containing the whole layout?

Comment: i was reading into Ajax but so far i can only manage to load a static <div id="2">value</div>, what i want is for the table to be blank unless a button is clicked on a different page... the iframe thing also wouldn't work for me because i don't want anyone to see the contents of the table on "page2" till i redirect them to it... i guess i'd like the buttons to function like "add to cart" buttons and for the table to be on another page functioning like a "cart" displaying which buttons had been clicked... the table will just have links to downloadable content depending on what was clicked...

Comment: Usually, a shopping cart functionality is implemented by having the web page POST some data to the server and the server saving it in a database or in the user's session. The server, after processing the post, replies with a web page filled using the information it stored.

Comment: Ye I can sort of understand how that works, php right? Thing is I technically have no idea about php, thought there might be a really simple way to achieve the same thing with js maybe...

Comment: You might want to look into setting and reading a cookie in Javascript. As mentioned here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

Ok! So I found a very insightful starter tutorial on cookies [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470821), which lead me to a productive night and some results atleast for now... heres what i have...

```
//this is to send the cookie "cooked"

<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
cookie_name = "cooked";
var send;

function putCookie() {

if(document.cookie != document.cookie) 
{index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);}
else 
{ index = -1;}
if (index == -1)
{
send=document.it.itr.value;
document.cookie=cookie_name+"="+send+"; expires=Wednesday, 01-Jan-2020 05:00:00 GMT";}
}
</SCRIPT>

<FORM NAME="it">
Enter A Word: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="itr" size="20">
<INPUT TYPE="button" Value="send cookies!" 
onClick="putCookie()">
</FORM>

<body/>
</head>
<html/>


//this is to receive the cookie "cooked"

<html>
<head>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

cookie_name = "cooked";
var received;

function getName() {
if(document.cookie)
{
index = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name);
if (index != -1)
{
namestart = (document.cookie.indexOf("=", index) + 1);
nameend = document.cookie.indexOf(";", index);
if (nameend == -1) {nameend = document.cookie.length;}
received = document.cookie.substring(namestart, nameend);
return received;
}
}
}

received=getName();
if (received == "cooked")
{received = "Nothing_Entered"}
</SCRIPT> 


<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
document.write("<FORM>")
document.write("you wrote:") 
document.write("<INPUT TYPE=text SIZE=30 VALUE=" +received+ ">");
document.write("</FORM>")
</SCRIPT>
    </BODY>
    </head>
    </HTML>


which works great, although it obviously won't function on ios...
```